# Rotate Wildfly log to a different directory

Tags: wildfly

We're using Wildfly 23. With the `periodic-rotating-file-handler` in standalone.xml, I see that I can add `.zip` to the `suffix` to compress it. That's great, but it's only step 1. I would also prefer for the rotated file to be in a different directory once it's rotated and zipped. It would be relative to the current log file's directory and the end directory would need to have the date, just like the suffix does.

Is this possible with what's already present and usable in standalone.xml? I've looked around online for examples and documentation, but it looks like it's all copied from each other and doesn't really add new information beyond what's already shown in the default standalone.xml file.

Comment: This is not possible. You'd need to write a custom handler to do that.